# Microsoft Outlook 2010 ignoring mso conditional comments

Tags: outlook, html-email, outlook-2010

In the `<head></head>` of my email's HTML I have:

```
<!--[if !mso]><!-->
<style>
    .contentTable {
        border: 1px solid #f00;
    }
</style>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

This `<style>` block should not be parsed in Outlook, but when testing in Outlook 2010 on PC, the table has the red border. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
<!--[if !mso]><!-->
```

Try this instead:

```
<!--[if !mso]><!-- -->
```

Using your code as an example, this will be hidden from Outlook:

```
<!--[if !mso]><!-- --><style type="text/css">
  .contentTable {border: 1px solid #f00;}
</style><![endif]-->
```

This code will show only in Outlook:

```
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]><style type="text/css">
  .contentTable {border: 1px solid #f00;}
</style><![endif]-->
```

I tested the following code in Litmus. In a modern email client, you will see a blue box. In Outlook 2007-2010, 2013, 2016, you will see a red box.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title>Outlook Images</title>
</head>
<body style="background: #ffffff !important;">
<table>
  <tr>
<td>
    <!--[if !mso]><!-- -->
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/0000ff/?text=Modern+Email" alt="Modern+Email" width="100%" style="display:inline-block;border:none;outline:none;padding:0;margin:0;width:100%;height:auto;" border="0" hspace="0" vspace="0">
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/ff0000?text=Outlook" alt="" width="100%" style="display:inline-block;border:none;outline:none;padding:0;margin:0;width:100%;height:auto;" border="0" hspace="0" vspace="0">
    <![endif]-->
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

- https://jsfiddle.net/wallyglenn/5hruzos5/

Good luck.

Comment: Outlook ignoring that block of code is exactly what I want. Outlook is still parsing everything inside of that condition though.

Comment: I mis-read your question. Instead of this: `<!--[if !mso]><!-->`, try this: `<!--[if !mso]><!-- -->`. I tested this in Litmus and it works in 2010. I rewrote my answer above and posted better example code. Good luck.

Comment: Share the love. Great answer.